# Amazon SMS for single number from c# sdk without creating topic

Tags: c#, sms, amazon-sns

As per the docs, to send an SMS for single number, we need not create SNS topic.
Clearly, they have given a sample code which shows we can set phone number for publish request method

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html

As per the java docs, I can clearly see that method.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/model/PublishRequest.html#setPhoneNumber-java.lang.String-

But, how do we implement same in c#? I couldn't find any method to send an sms without creating an SNS topic.

Can someone guide me how do I send an SMS without creating an SNS topic from C# SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll find the answer here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=250183&tstart=0

Basically what is saying and quote: "...PhoneNumber property was added in version 3.1.1.0 of AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService..."

I haven't put example code since the **PhoneNumber** property is what is missing in the request, the rest should work as similar to Java Example :D.

Comment: Link is not working. It is saying The specified thread [0] was not found.

Comment: I tested the link myself again and is working is probably no available for your location, I updated the answer with the comment they put inside the forum. I was in the same situation and after upgrade the package version I was able to see the property.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

```
var smsAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>();
MessageAttributeValue senderID = new MessageAttributeValue();
senderID.DataType = "String";
senderID.StringValue = "mySenderId";

MessageAttributeValue sMSType = new MessageAttributeValue();
sMSType.DataType = "String";
sMSType.StringValue = "Promotional";

////MessageAttributeValue maxPrice = new MessageAttributeValue();
////maxPrice.DataType = "Number";
////maxPrice.StringValue = "0.1";

CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;

smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", senderID);
smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", sMSType);
////smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", maxPrice);

PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
publishRequest.Message = vm.Message;
publishRequest.MessageAttributes = smsAttributes;
publishRequest.PhoneNumber = vm.PhoneNumber;
AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(vm.AccessKey, vm.SecretKey, config);
AmazonSNSResponse resp = new AmazonSNSResponse();
await client.PublishAsync(publishRequest);

AmazonSNSResponse response = new AmazonSNSResponse();
response.Status = HttpStatusCode.OK.ToString();
response.Message = "Success";
return response;
```

Answer (score -1):

See [`Publish(PublishRequest)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SNS/MSNSSNSPublishPublishRequest.html).

[`Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.PublishRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SNS/TSNSPublishRequest.html) has a `PhoneNumber` property, used for setting the number when sending a direct SMS message.

Comment: sample code will help. I have used the same library. But not able to get a method which can set phone number @Michael