# Sending an SMS Message to a Phone Number AWS SNS C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send an SMS message to a phone number in asp.net mvc.

I am getting issue of a phone number in the publish object.

"Publish Request does not contain a defination of Phone Number."

```
  using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
  using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model;
 string number = "00000000";
 string message = "Hello at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
 var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(region: 
              Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
 var request = new PublishRequest
 {
    Message = message,
    PhoneNumber = number
  };
  var response = client.Publish(request);
```

Comment: Yes I am adding the country code

Comment: You could check this out and see if it helps: [amazon-sms-for-single-number-from-c-sharp-sdk-without-creating-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140305/amazon-sms-for-single-number-from-c-sharp-sdk-without-creating-topic)

Comment: Also, check your versioning: [phonenumber-is-not-a-member-of-publishrequest-aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720875/phonenumber-is-not-a-member-of-publishrequest-aws)

Comment: `number` doesn't look like a valid E.164 phone number.  Does your code work if you use a valid phone number?

Comment: Yes,  the code is working fine. I just need to install the separate SDKs. previously I am using AWS SDK only